# What operation contract can I put for my WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application that I intend to let it interact with a server. The server will receive posting from a mobile application that I have developed and whenever a posting is received, my Windows Form Application should be notified and give me a notification. And for now I am starting to create a WCF service for it.

This is a sample scenario of what I meant,

E.g. My mobile application sends an message over to my server. Once my server receives the message, my windows form application should display a new notification showing the content of the message received.

so for the operationcontract of the service, what type of methods should i put in in order for me to receive the posting?

e.g.

```
[OperationContract]
bool receivePosting(int n);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite clear as to which direction you want to communicate:

- your "server" needs to notify the Winforms app of a new posting that's been saved?

or:

- your Winforms app asks the "server" about new postings??

I put "server" in quotes because in WCF world, that's a term being used for a specific role.

Assuming the first option, you need to do this:

- your Winforms app needs to be the WCF server - e.g. it needs to define a service contract, operation contract and data contract - and implement those
- your "posting server" would be the WCF **client** in this case; whenever a posting is received/stored, then you would call the WCF service in your Winforms app to send a notification (so really, in this setup, your roles are reserved - the Winforms app is the WCF server)

As for the operation contract - what does your Winforms app need to know about the new posting? Just the fact a new posting has been received? The whole contents of the posting, or just parts of it??

In any case, you need to define a method on your WCF service that the "posting server" can call and pass all relevant info to the Winforms WCF Server - you don't want to have to make two or more calls just for one notification.

So you Service Contract might be:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPostingService 
{
   [OperationContract]
   void NotifyAboutPosting(Posting post);
}
```

and your `Posting` class would be the data contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class Posting
{
   [DataMember]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public string Description { get; set; }
   [DataMember]
   public DateTime PostingTimestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Whatever you need to send between those two parties - define it in your data contract which is the argument to your service call

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. I have edited my main post above. What I want is when my server receives a new posting of message/event , I need to capture that posting and sends it to my winforms app to notify me that I have received a new posting with the information in it.

Comment: edit : what do I need to import for using the datacontract schema?

Comment: @Thomas: `DataContract` lives in the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace

Comment: it says that the modifier 'public' is not valid for the notifyaboutposting item.

Comment: @Thomas: sorry, yes, in the interface, you cannot define `public` - just remove it

Comment: hi. thanks for the reply. mind guiding me what is the next step that i should do to continue to develop this service? as im still new in this area im pretty unsure of what I should do next. for the datamember those methods are used for retrieving the information of the posting that i get from the server right?

Comment: Once you have the service contract in place, you need to **implement** the service method in your Winforms app. Once you have that, start your app, now you should be able to use e.g. [the WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) tool to connect to your service, to see that it's up and running and functioning properly.

Comment: When you have that, your next step would be to go to your "posting" server and incorporate a client-side proxy to that WCF service that's up and running, e.g. by using "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio or using the svcutil.exe command line tool. Once you have that, your "posting server" can now make calls to that Notification service so that your Winforms app gets notified when new postings have arrived